# how to combine registration and billing for the program

Tags: c

the code is register and billing for the hospital that use for some program I can't combine the code together and it could construct program that register and count for the bill that count that

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int check_pass(int pass);
    int main()
    {
        int x,pass;
        for(x=0;x<5;x++){
        printf("Enter your password: ");
        scanf("%d",&pass);
        check_pass(pass);
        if(pass==1234){
        break;}
        }
        return 0;
    }
    int check_pass(int pass)
    {
        if(pass == 1234){
            printf("Password is correct\n");
            printf("==============  Hospital City  =============== ");
        }
        else{
            printf("Password is wrong, please try again\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

the another code is for billing for patient that program thank for the help but the code is very blurred for me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int id,day1,mnth1,year1,day2,mnth2,year2;
    int days,Bill;
    printf("ID: ");
    scanf("%d",&id);
    printf("Date in (MM/DD/YYYY): ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d",&mnth1,&day1,&year1);
    printf("Date out (MM/DD/YYYY): ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d",&mnth2,&day2,&year2);

    days = day2 - day1;
    printf("Number of days: %d days\n",days);
    Bill = days*10;
    printf("Bill to pay:%d x RM10 = RM%d\n",days,Bill);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define specification of things to create (combined program in this case) first.

Comment: Just as a side note: It is unsafe to use `scanf` without checking the return value. See this page for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. You may want to read this: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/12149471)

Comment: Just to be clear....you do not know how to edit in a function, rename it and call it from main()?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes - I've edited my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of an unclear question, but I will attempt to answer.

Break your code into modules. This means, put functionality into functions and not in main. Then, you can call them whenever from wherever.

```
int get_bill()
{
    int id,day1,mnth1,year1,day2,mnth2,year2;
    int days,Bill;
    printf("ID: ");
    scanf("%d",&id);
    printf("Date in (MM/DD/YYYY): ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d",&mnth1,&day1,&year1);
    printf("Date out (MM/DD/YYYY): ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d",&mnth2,&day2,&year2);

    days = day2 - day1;
    printf("Number of days: %d days\n",days);
    Bill = days*10;
    printf("Bill to pay:%d x RM10 = RM%d\n",days,Bill);

    return Bill;
}
```

You can then call this from main after the user enters a password.